# Change all index of pandas series to one value

Tags: python, pandas, series

I'm trying to change all index values of a pandas series to one value. I have 200k+ rows and the index is a number from 0 to 200k+. I want the index to be a single string, for example 'Token'. Is this possible with pandas? I've tried reindex but that doesnt seem to work, I think that would only work if i would give a 200k list of 'token' as argument which is not what I want to do.

Comment: thanks for your response this is indeed what I want to do but since it is a series it gives me an error AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'insert' is there a similar method for a series? I cant find it in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Use insert and set_index, like example here below:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [1, 2, 3], 'C': [4, 5, 6]})
    df
    Out: 
           B  C
        0  1  4
        1  2  5
        2  3  6

    idx = 0
    index_string = 'token'
    df.insert(loc=idx, column='A', value=index_string)
    df.set_index('A', inplace=True)
    df

    Out: 
            B   C
    A       
    token   1   4
    token   2   5
    token   3   6
```